# SDDL string for Local Service

Tags: windows, security, permissions

I'm having a hard time constructing an SDDL string, for Local Service, that enables the following permissions only: List folder contents, Read, Write

Is it not possible to have only these three permissions without 'Read & execute'? For example: (A;OICI;RCCRWPRPLCDCCCSD;;;LS) enables the following: Read & execute, List Folder contents, Read, Write

[MSDN Link for ACE Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374928(v=vs.85).aspx)

[image]

Comment: What sort of object are you securing?  Something in the AD?

Comment: Just a regular folder. I am setting the string in a Wix XML file to set permissions on a folder.

Comment: In that case, why all the AD permissions (RP, WP, LC, etc.)?  For a file you should be using the file permissions or the generic permissions.  Try RCGRGW.  (Although it is unusual to leave out execute permission; do you have a specific reason for wanting to do so?)